# Why does loop stop on integer 1?

Tags: vb.net, loops, integer

Why does loop stop, on `proov = 1`, but I have it looped until 10?
It should add +1 on each round but program stops on 1.

```
Dim proov As Integer
        proov = 0

        Dim myClientMachineAddressList = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(System.Net.Dns.GetHostName())
        Do
            Dim myClientMachineIP = myClientMachineAddressList.AddressList(proov)
            If myClientMachineIP.AddressFamily = Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork Then
                Label2.Text = myClientMachineIP.ToString()
            Else
                TextBox2.Text = "IP does not equal to IPv4"
            End If
            Thread.Sleep(1000)
            proov = proov + 1
            TextBox3.Text = proov.ToString()
        Loop Until proov = 10
```

Comment: Did you get an exception? Like `Index out of range`?

Comment: Most likely the code above Thread.Sleep is provoking an error. To confirm this issue, put all this code inside a try...catch block and confirm that the loop goes until the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this

```
    Dim proov As Integer = 0
    Dim myClientMachineAddressList As System.Net.IPHostEntry = System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(System.Net.Dns.GetHostName())
    Do While proov < myClientMachineAddressList.AddressList.Length
        Dim myClientMachineIP As System.Net.IPAddress = myClientMachineAddressList.AddressList(proov)
        'your code here
        'Debug.WriteLine(myClientMachineIP.ToString)
        proov += 1
    Loop
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have less that 10 AddressList your code will fail with an Index out of range exception.

Change your test condition to

```
   Do
       ....
   Loop Until proov >= myClientMachineAddressList.AddressList.Length
```

Answer (score 0):

Varocarbas' comment helped alot! Thank you good sir!
Quote:

> Most likely the code above Thread.Sleep is provoking an error. To
>   confirm this issue, put all this code inside a try...catch block and
>   confirm that the loop goes until the end